# Python url issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Hey guys so i am trying out python and i have the following code that returns me a urllib.error.URLERROR:

```
import sys
import urllib.request
urlToRead = "http://www.google.ca"
crawledWebLinks = {}
while urlToRead !='':
    try:
        urlToRead = input("Please enter the next URL to crawl")
        if urlToRead == "":
            break
        shortName = input("Please enter a short name for that Url "+ urlToRead)
        webFile = urllib.request.urlopen(urlToRead).read()
        crawledWebLinks[shortName] = webFile

    except:
        print("Unexpected Error", sys.exc_info()[0])
        stopOrProceed = input("Hmm...stop or proceed? Enter 1 to stop and enter anything else to continue.")
        if stopOrProceed == 1:
            print ("Okey-Dokey\n")
            break
        else:
            continue

print(crawledWebLinks.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing the exception message:

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected Error", e)
```

this will give you more information than just the exception class. Instead of just "URLError", you might see something more informative like `<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>`.